# I want my Angular 6 app to work with Google Jobs but cannot format correctly

Tags: angular, webpack, angular6

I want my html job posting to appear in google jobs.

This is the schema: https://schema.org/JobPosting

But the SPA takes too long to get the app loading and jobs showing so the crawlers not picking up the jobs.

**This is my code example:**

```
 <meta itemprop="address" content="{{ job.address.addressLine1 }} {{ job.address.postCode }}">
 <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="{{ job.address.country }}">

 <p class="flex justify-between">
     <span itemprop="industry"><strong>{{ job.sector }}</strong></span>
     <span *ngIf="job.datePosted" itemprop="datePosted"><strong>{{ job.datePosted }}</strong></span>
 </p>

 <h3>
     <span itemprop="title">{{ job.name }}</span>
     <span itemprop="baseSalary">{{ job.pay.currency }}{{ job.pay.value }}</span>
 </h3>

 <p itemprop="description" [innerHtml]="job.description"></p>
```

As you can see I've added the "itemprop".

**Tech stack:** Angular Version 6, Webpack, Angular Cli 6

When I use this tool from google jobs it doesnt show the jobs: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/

Comment: You need to use something like Angular Universal to render the page for you.

Comment: Hi! I wanted to know if you resolved this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into server side rendering for serving the initial load of your angular app. That way google will always get the final load of your page as it will be rendered on the server before they get it.

The difficulty in setting it up really depends on what your backend stack is, and how complex your web app is.

Comment: I’m just using node js. I’m a front end developer so would prefer a simple front end solution to this